# Including a variable when calling an Access User Defined Function

Tags: ms-access, user-defined-functions

I have an Access User Defined Function to count the number of files in a specific folder
The folder associated to each record, has the record ID number in its name:
i.e. record ID number 2789 will have the documents stored in O:\DOCS\PROCESS**2789**

My problem is how to include the ID field when I call the function from a text box

I´ve tried with no success:

=ContaAnexos("O:\DOCS\PROCESS & [Me.ID]")

=ContaAnexos("O:\DOCS\PROCESS” & (Me.ID))

```
Function ContaAnexos(folderspec As String) As Integer

'  Returns a count of files in folderspec, or -1 if folder does not exist

Dim fso As Object

   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   If fso.FolderExists(folderspec) Then
      ContaAnexos = fso.GetFolder(folderspec).Files.Count
   Else
      ContaAnexos = -1
   End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (no smart quotes af PROCESS):

```
=ContaAnexos("O:\DOCS\PROCESS" & [ID] & "")
```

Comment: Yes, its working! In my case:  =ContaAnexos("O: \DOCS\PROCESS" & [ID] & "")… Thanks a lot.

Comment: Of course. It's a controlsource. I've edited the answer.